# Which LTE antennas to buy for a passive repeater?

Tags: 4g, antennas

I want to improve the LTE signal that I receive indoor where I work and after some researching I'm thinking about a **passive LTE repeater** `(Outdoor Antenna <--> Cable <--> Indoor Antenna)`.
However; I am not sure which LTE antennas to buy.

The LTE bands that I want to repeat are mainly:

- **B20 ( 800 MHz)**
- B8    ( 900 MHz)
- **B3  (1800 MHz)**
- **B1  (2100 MHz)**
- B7  (2600 MHz)

with my mobile operators in Italy being:

1. [Vodafone](https://www.spectrum-tracker.com/Italy/Vodafone)
2. [Iliad](https://www.spectrum-tracker.com/Italy/ILIAD)
3. [Wind-Tre](https://www.spectrum-tracker.com/Italy/Wind-Tre)

The nearest **LTE BTS** to which my phone connects are:

1. 4G+ 4CA (**B7 B1 B3 B20**) [2 km away]
2. 4G+ 4CA (**B7 B1 B3 B20**) [8.5 km away]

This is a [NetMonster](https://netmonster.app/) screenshot from indoor room R1 ground floor.
[image]

and this from outdoor point A

[image]

My Speed Tests from room R1 are:

- https://www.speedtest.net/result/a/9997810653
- https://www.speedtest.net/result/a/9997817404

While from the outside at pint A, the results are much better.

- https://www.speedtest.net/result/a/9996998222
- https://www.speedtest.net/result/a/9996984057

The building is as follows, divided in two floors (3M + 3M high)
and I want to **improve the LTE signal in the room R1** (groud and first floor) by installing a **passive LTE repeater** with **two antennas** in points **A** and **B** connected via a coaxial cable (in red).
The **LTE BTS** are located on the left of point A.

[image]

Which are the best LTE antennas and coaxial cable to use in this case?
For the outdoor antenna I think it is betteter an omnidirectional MIMO considering that there are two near BTSs and the outdoor signal is good enough.
Regarding the indoor antenna I don't known what to use. Is a generic MIMO good enough?
Do they have a specific name?

Will the indoor antenna installed at point B be able to improve the signal also for rooms R0, R2, R4 ?

Are the  NETGEAR 6000451 omnidirectional https://amzn.eu/d/aHk3mko and the KASER K5GPB14V3 180° directonal https://amzn.eu/d/8qF74CU
ok for my case?

**Update 1**

The outdoor antenna is installed at 6 meters from the ground, while the indoor antenna is at 2.5 meters from the ground.

I first bought the **KASER K5GPB14V3 180°** and the **NETGEAR 6000451**, connected them using the pair of **10 meters coax cables**, and I was able to get around 5 times the speed (both download and upload) I had without them, but only if I literally placed my phone on top of the NETGEAR indoor antenna.

I thought it was the fault of the indoor antenna, so I replaced it with a Kaser OmniDirectional https://www.kaserstore.com/collections/mondo-4g-5g-lte/products/kaser-antenna-5g-4g-lte-esterno-mimo-omnidirezionale-698-2700-3300-3800-mhz-guadagno-fino-12-dbi-cavi-da-10m

The two antennas are now connected using the 20 meters pair of cables,
however I can not notice any improvement even with the smartphone placed on top of the indoor antenna.
Is it due to the length of the cambles? I may connect them using just the 10 meters cables by using another pair of connectors, but I fear it will not have enough power to cover at least room R1.

Which amplifiers should I buy if this is the case?
Do I need a Bi-Directional Amplifier (BDA)? Can I replace a BDA with two amplifiers (one to amplify the oudoor antenna and the other to amplify the indoor antenna)? E.g. HTOOL HT004 100K-6GHz https://it.aliexpress.com/item/1005005950859267.html
Notice that each antenna is MIMO and has two cables.

**Update 2**

Now the setup of the antennas is as follows:

- [A KASER MIMO 180°](https://www.kaserstore.com/collections/mondo-4g-5g-lte/products/kaser-antenna-5g-4g-lte-pannello-esterno-mimo-698-2700-3300-3800-mhz-guadagno-fino-12-dbi-cavi-da-10m-v3) = 6 meters from the ground
  [image]
- [B KASER OMNI 360°](https://www.kaserstore.com/collections/mondo-4g-5g-lte/products/kaser-antenna-5g-4g-lte-esterno-mimo-omnidirezionale-698-2700-3300-3800-mhz-guadagno-fino-12-dbi-cavi-da-10m) = 2.5 meters from the ground
  [image]

The red line connecting the antennas are two cables of total length 20 meters. I would like the antenna B to serve at least both the ground and the first floor of room R1 and the top half of room R0 at ground floor.
[image]